# Include files in src/main/resources in runnable jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I use `mvn clean install` to generate a runnable jar file. But when I run it on another machine, I get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` for a file located in the resource folder. Do the files in the resources folder get included in the runnable jar file?

I'm using the file like below

```
ClassLoader classLoader = new MyServiceApplication().getClass().getClassLoader();

FileInputStream serviceAccount = null;
try {
    serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(classLoader.getResource("edge-9d2a9-firebase-adminsdk-ym42z-1bc1ae9164.json").getFile());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can you unzip the produced jar file and see if the file is in there?

Comment: yes, they are in "BOOT-INF/classes"

Comment: Shouldn't the file be under resources?

Comment: Not sure, maven is doing this. I did put it in the resources folder though

Comment: The file "edge-....-9164.json" should be in package of MyServiceApplication class. please take a look. that is the issue.

Comment: I changed `FileInputStream` to `InputStream serviceAccount` and it looks like it's working now